# PHP Mailer has to show an error if SMTP login fails?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've set:

```
$mail->IsSmtp();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'my.host.net';
/*
here I didn't writed my login and password

*/
```

I don't know if the login and password is needed when i Use smtp mail sending, but there is no error, can be that because my host doesn't require login or password?

Comment: using smtp u need that.

Comment: if(!$this->smtp->Authenticate($this->Username, $this->Password)) { 
610             $this->SetError($this->Lang('authenticate')); 
611             $this->smtp->Reset(); 
612             $connection = false; 
613           }

Comment: so it could be that server always returns true, if he doesn't need the login and password and thats why there is no erros, but i doubt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be that the server doesn't require login or password.